# How to use an arrow inside the title of a plot?

Tags: r, plot

how can I use an right arrow inside the title of a barplot?
I tried the following:

```
counts <- c(0.2, 0.4)
barplot(counts, main="A → B", horiz=TRUE, col=2:3, xlab="Time", xlim=c(0, 1.0))
```

In R the title of the plot looks good but when I save the plot to file, e.g. pdf, the right arrow in the title is replaced by three dots '...'.

I am using R under Windows 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `expression()` :

```
set.seed(1)
d1 <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), x = rnorm(100))

plot(y ~ x, data = d1,ylab = expression(y %->% x),xlab = expression(x %->% y))
```

List of expressions can be found at : https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html

Comment: It is working except for the following plot command: barplot(counts, main=expression(Leere ABC: FMdsfdf %->% NLKdf))

Comment: Use `barplot(counts, main=expression(Leere~ABC:~FMdsfdf %->% NLKdf))`

Comment: There is some odd behaviour here ( i think) but this works `main=expression("Leere Flasche FMdsfdf:" %->% "NLKdf")`

Comment: If you are calling that "odd behavior" then it means you don't understand R expressions. And that's no surprise since the ?plotmath page doesn't do a very good job of explaining the parsing rules that govern what is valid. Heck, in truth it does a terrible job.

Comment: I agree, don't understand them as well as I should. Sadly am more of a practitioner so I tend to stop digging as soon as the job at hand is done :) Work Hazards!! Could you refer to any link which is useful? Thanks!

Comment: My knowledge has come from on-the-job experience. The basic rule is that the contents of expression get passed to `parse` and need to be able to form a valid "parse-tree". This means that pairs of symbol or sub-expression (in the R sense of the terms) need to be separated by an "operator. The most useful non-math operators are `*` and `~`.  This rule also means that reserved R words like `in` or `for` need quotes. Unquoted numeric expressions with leading 0's will have those dropped.

Comment: Not working if I don't have anything on the right side: expression(y%->%)

Answer (score 2):

The current answer is correct but I thought I would add some tips on extending it to situations where there were no plotmath `%...%` infix operators for a "special character". The `?plotmath` page refers us to the `points` page for Symbol-font characters and this is a modified version of the `TestChars()` function defined there that has octal (or optionally decimal) values needed to choose one of the displayed glyphs on your system:

```
TestCharsSym <- function(sign = 1, font = 5, oct = TRUE, ...)
{
  MB <- l10n_info()$MBCS
  r <- if(font == 5) { 
    sign <- 1
    c(32:126, 160:254)
  } else {
    if(MB) 32:126 else 32:255
  }
  if (sign == -1) r <- c(32:126, 160:255)
  par(pty = "s")
  plot(c(-1, 16), c(-1, 16), 
       type = "n", 
       xlab = "", 
       ylab = "",
       xaxs = "i", 
       yaxs = "i",
       main = sprintf("sign = %d, font = %d", sign, font)
  )
  grid(17, 17, lty = 1)
  mtext(paste("MBCS:", MB, "  Use symbol(\"...\") "))
  for(i in r){ 
    try(points(i%%16, i%/%16, pch = sign*i, font = font, ...))
    text(i%%16 - 0.3, i%/%16 - 0.3, 
         if( oct ){ 
           paste0("\\", as.octmode(i))
         } else{
           i
         },
         cex = 0.5)
  }
}
TestCharsSym()
```

[image]

My system is OSX as could be seen if you were looking at my interactive plot device for the 240-glyph but the `pdf()` device no longer uses the Apple Symbol font. To use this information in an expression with `*symbol(...)`, you need to "encode" the decimal value in octal and pass to that `plotmath()` function with a preceding quoted backslash. The forward arrow could be produced with:

```
main=expression(A *symbol('\256')* B)
```

Comment: @Andrie: Your editing efforts appreciated. I'm taking those efforts as an implicit endorsement.  If you want to suggest further enhancements to this function, you should feel free. I have found this table sufficiently useful that I post it on the side of my "tower".

Comment: :-) Definitely endorsement. I enjoyed this answer and working through the code trying to understand what it does. I definitely agree that the help for `?plotmath` has scope for improvement!